# PHP and SQL unable to send data from database

Tags: php, html, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Tried checking the variables the page can submit the but the data can't be send to the database, already checked everything and i don't know if i missed something.

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

```
    $applicant_ilname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['applicant_ilname']);
    $applicant_ifname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['applicant_ifname']);
    $applicant_imname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['applicant_imname']);
    $isingle = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['isingle']);
    $imarried = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['imarried']);
    $iwidow = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['iwidow']);
    $iwidower = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['iwidower']);
    $imale = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['imale']);
    $ifemale = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ifemale']);
    $initial_age = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['initial_age']);
    $initial_homeaddress = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['initial_homeaddress']);
    $ibMonth = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ibMonth']);
    $idateDay = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['idateDay']);
    $ibYear = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ibYear']);
    $ibPlace = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ibPlace']);
    $aiPurpose = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['aiPurpose']);


    $_SESSION['applicant_ilname'] = $applicant_ilname;
    $_SESSION['applicant_ifname'] = $applicant_ifname;
    $_SESSION['applicant_imname'] = $applicant_imname;
    $_SESSION['isingle'] = $isingle;
    $_SESSION['imarried'] = $imarried;
    $_SESSION['iwidow'] = $iwidow;
    $_SESSION['iwidower'] = $iwidower;
    $_SESSION['imale'] = $imale;
    $_SESSION['ifemale'] = $ifemale;
    $_SESSION['initial_age'] = $initial_age;
    $_SESSION['ibMonth'] = $ibMonth;
    $_SESSION['idateDay'] = $idateDay;
    $_SESSION['ibYear'] = $ibYear;
    $_SESSION['ibPlace'] = $ibPlace;
    $_SESSION['aiPurpose'] = $aiPurpose;


    $sql = "INSERT INTO initialform (applicant_ilname, applicant_ifname, applicant_imname, isingle, imarried, iwidow, iwidower, imale, ifemale, initial_age, ibMonth, idateDay, ibYear, ibPlace, aiPurpose)" ."VALUES('$applicant_ilname', '$applicant_ifname', '$applicant_imname', '$isingle', '$imarried', '$iwidow', '$iwidower', '$imale', '$ifemale', '$initial_age', '$ibMonth', '$idateDay', '$ibYear', '$ibPlace', '$ibPlace', '$aiPurpose')";


  }


?>
```

Comment: I don't see where you're querying/executing.

Comment: ...or my eyes deceive me.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "execution" part of the query.

At the end of the file right after the $sql= add:

```
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Where $conn is the var where you configured the database connection.

Also remember, despite $mysqli->real_escape_string is a good thing, you must validate your data or you may fall into trying to insert a null or string value into the wrong field.

Try to use **[prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)** and **[catch the error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)**.

Comment: This is more of a comment [which has already been said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590345/php-and-sql-unable-to-send-data-from-database#comment80133712_46590345) than an answer. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation, including code, of what to do and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO initialform (applicant_ilname, applicant_ifname, applicant_imname, isingle, imarried, iwidow, iwidower, imale, ifemale, initial_age, ibMonth, idateDay, ibYear, ibPlace, aiPurpose)" ."VALUES('$applicant_ilname', '$applicant_ifname', '$applicant_imname', '$isingle', '$imarried', '$iwidow', '$iwidower', '$imale', '$ifemale', '$initial_age', '$ibMonth', '$idateDay', '$ibYear', '$ibPlace', '$ibPlace', '$aiPurpose')";

  $myData = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      }

is this what you mean to put executing query

Comment: @Mark: ... that is only a string, potentially ready to be sent to the DB. However, the string alone will not automatically send itself to the DB. Other DB-related functions are necessary to pass that string to the DB.  See [this simplified example](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/func_mysqli_query.asp) of making a DB connection and a couple of example queries using the function shown in this answer.